# Check that Await.result doesn't return anything

Tags: scala

I have added the function `delay` to `Future`, which makes a `Future` wait for a specified amount of time.

I have added the following unit test, which checks that it doesn't finish to early:

```
test("Wait - not too short") {
    def f: Future[Unit] = Future.delay(3 seconds)
    assert(Await.result(f, 1 seconds) == None)
  }
```

The problem is that when I run the test I am getting this error:

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: <(), the Unit value> did not equal None
```

This is probably because `Await.result` doesn't return `None` if the future isn't finished.

So what does it return when the future it waits for hasn't finished?

What value should I check for?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Await$

Comment: See `isReadyWithin` http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.6/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.Futures

Answer (score 1):

This is from memory (on phone at the moment). But if you don't give enough time for a Future it will through a TimeOutException (maybe FututeTimedOutException). So I expect your thought is not the case.

What I expect is Future delay isn't behaving exactly how you expect. To test this try:

```
Future(Thread.sleep(3000))
```

Comment: 100% that
Also see in docs for `Await.result`: `@throws TimeoutException         if after waiting for the specified time awaitable is still not ready`